# Jenkins Parallel Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script that currently does everything serially:

```
node('virtual'){
    stage('setup'){...}
    stage('build'){...}
    stage('test'){...}
    stage('clean'){...}
}
node('real'){
    stage('setup'){...}
    stage('build'){...}
    stage('test'){...}
    stage('clean'){...}
}
```

What is the best approach if i want to make it parallel? I know stages shouldn't/can't be in a parallel statement, but i need all those stages to occur on the same node. The commands do differ per node.

Would this be an acceptable solution? I do need the compiled output of Build to be accessible in Test and i want to minimize any `checkout scm` if i don't need them, except for the first one.

```
stage('setup'){
    parallel(
        virtual:{
            node('virtual'){
                // do work
                // stash what is needed
            }
        },
        real:{
            node('real'){
            // do work
            // stash what is needed
            }
        })
}
stage('setup'){
    parallel(
        virtual:{
            node('virtual'){
                //unstash setup
                // do work
                // stash what is needed
            }
        },
        real:{
            node('real'){
            // do work
            // stash what is needed
            }
        })
}
// continue for the rest...
```